# how to enable webgui after running auto-secure on ASR 1001-X Version 16.09.02

Tags: cisco

I've tried doing the following on the cisco [web-guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr1000/configuration/guide/chassis/xe-16-11/asr1000-software-config-guide-16-11/webui-asr.pdf) but have gotten no luck in restoring the webgui after running auto secure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should really disable the HTTP and HTTPS servers in the device if you want to secure the device.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, while looking at the running config I saw this

```
no ip source-route
no ip routing        <------- Issue was here
no ip gratuitous-arps
!
!
!
no ip bootp server
no ip domain lookup
```

I then type in `R1(config)#ip routing` and this helped me solve the issue of being able for the time enable the routing to access the webgui ip. Hope this help someone else in the future

Comment: I *very seriously* doubt auto-secure turned off *ip routing*. It will turn off the http server (`no ip http server`) -- which is 100% of your problem.